# AngularJS on IE10+ ,textarea with placeholder cause "Invalid argument."

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

I'm getting "*Invalid argument*" when using angularJS ,TextArea with placeholder, on IE10+.

This will ONLY happen when the textarea node is closed with `</textarea>` and will not happen when I close the textarea now on itself.

**This will raise the "Invalid argument" exception:**

```
<div ng-app>
    <input ng-model="placeholderModel" type="text"/>
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="{{placeholderModel}}" ng-model="textareaModel"></textarea>
</div>
```

**This will work with no problems:**

```
<div ng-app>
    <input ng-model="placeholderModel" type="text"/>
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="{{placeholderModel}}" ng-model="textareaModel"/>
</div>
```

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/huecc/

Comment: This has just solved another bug with IE, Angular and textareas. Thank you!

Comment: Still exist: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025

Comment: just an fyi: I'm getting the same issue on Android chrome.

Comment: What is the webpage SUPPOSED to display?

Comment: in IE10+: even this:
`<div ng-app>
<input ng-model="buyer_message" type="text"/>
<textarea id="message" placeholder="{{buyer_message}}" ></textarea>
</div>`
works strange. It updates placeholder and content both :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the way you're binding to the element's placeholder - strange, I know.

I was able to get everything working correctly in IE using the [ng-attr-placeholder](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) directive instead of binding directly to the attribute in the DOM.

For example, *instead of:*

```
<textarea placeholder="{{placeholderModel}}" ng-model="textareaModel"></textarea>
```

**Try this:**

```
<textarea ng-attr-placeholder="placeholderModel" ng-model="textareaModel"></textarea>
```

**Related:** [AngularJS v1.2.5 script error with textarea and placeholder attribute using IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24272011/1796930)

Comment: `ngAttrPlaceholder` seems to be deprecated. If you still want to use this approach, you may need to use a custom directive as demonstrated [here](https://gist.github.com/mbenford/dd7556f01963f49e5c7d). Or you can just add a space between <textarea> </textarea> as suggested by the other answer.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this error today and randomly stumbled upon this question. Here's what solved it for me

**Before:**

```
<textarea placeholder="{[{ 'NAME' | translate }]}" ng-model="name" name="name"></textarea>
```

**After:**

```
<textarea placeholder="{[{ 'NAME' | translate }]}" ng-model="name" name="name"> </textarea>
```

Note the little space inside the textarea, that's what actually stopped IE from complaining...

Comment: That didn't work for me, but you got me on the right track! I used: translate>{{'TRANSLATE_ME'}}< and had this issue (works everywhere BUT all versions of IE...). When I switched to: >{{'TRANSLATE_ME' | translate}}< it works even in IE.

Comment: It does not throw an error anymore but it doesn't show the placeholder text either. Except you delete the space afterwards

Comment: True, they probably fixed it in Windows 10. I actually ended up having a directive that does `element.innerText = '';` to every textarea, because I didn't want to bother having to remember to leave a space in all textareas.

Comment: The fact that this works is a proof that IE sucks! Tx! @F.H.; make sure to keep the close tag of the text area on the same line as the open tag (obviously, only needed for IE).

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is now pretty old, but thought I'd throw in my thoughts too.  We ran into this issue several months ago and had to drum up a fix, so we ended up using this directive to solve the problem:

```
mod.directive('placeHolder', [
    function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                scope.$watch(attrs.placeHolder, function(newVal,oldVal){
                    elem.attr('placeholder', newVal);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

And then you can use it in your views:

```
<textarea place-holder="placeholderModel" ng-model="textareaModel"></textarea>
```

Once your model data arrives (possibly asynchronously), the directive will add a traditional `placeholder` attribute to the `<textarea>` and it'll work as you would want.

It's not the greatest solution, but it works.  Hope that helps.

Comment: No need to write a custom directive when us can use the [ng-attr-placeholder](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) directive instead. :)

Comment: I honestly had no idea the `ng-attr-*` directive existed. That sounds like it would definitely do the trick.