# AngularJS v1.2.5 script error with textarea and placeholder attribute using IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, angularjs

I have an Angular JS v1.2.5 form that won't work in IE11. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. My form uses a textarea with interpolation inside the placeholder attribute.

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{ name }}!</p>
    <textarea rows="4" placeholder="Description of the {{ name }}"></textarea>
  </body>
```

If the placeholder attribute is specified with interpolation, I get the following error (only in IE).

```
Error: Invalid argument.
   at interpolateFnWatchAction (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/angular.js:6410:15)
   at $digest (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/angular.js:11581:23)
   at $apply (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/angular.js:11832:13)
   at done (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/angular.js:7774:34)
   at completeRequest (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/angular.js:7947:7)
   at onreadystatechange (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/angular.js:7903:11)
```

Here's a Plnkr that works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari - but not in IE11.
http://plnkr.co/edit/4cJzxtVSDoL2JMI9nYrS?p=preview

I'm lost trying to debug within Angular.js itself. I'd really appreciate any tips to set me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the first thing to do is to reproduce it.

Comment: Working on it. In the meantime, hoping to find someone else who's had this problem.

Comment: Itr looks like it's on an ajax request, can you try faking the AJAX in your fiddle?  There's a URL JSFiddle has taht you can post to and get the same data back, check your network tab in dev tools an just post what you get back when you get the error to that.

Comment: I added a Plunkr above that reproduces the problem - thanks for the tips so far.

Comment: Bug. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025

Comment: zsong - thanks. This was a tricky one.

Comment: Duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224698/angularjs-on-ie10-textarea-with-placeholder-cause-invalid-argument

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I was able to get everything working correctly in IE using the [ng-attr-placeholder](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) directive instead of binding directly to the attribute in the DOM. For example:

```
<textarea ng-attr-placeholder="Description of the {{ name }}"></textarea>
```

Comment: This should be accepted anwser, no additional code required.

Comment: This solution works on IE11 / Angular 1.4.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Zsong mentioned above, this is a bug - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025

As a temporary measure, I wrote a directive to handle placeholders for text areas in IE. This directive will set the placeholder attribute as long as it's not IE. This should only be necessary on text areas (not all placeholders).

```
//This directive corrects an interpolation error with textarea / IE
app.directive("placeholderAttr", 
    function ($timeout, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {
                placeholderAttr: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                //Test for IE
                var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/);
                var ie11 = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./);

                //If this is IE, remove the placeholder attribute
                if (!ie && !ie11)
                {
                    scope.$watch("placeholderAttr", function (value) {
                        element.attr("placeholder", scope.$eval(value));
                    });
                }

            }
        };

    });
```

Usage:

```
<textarea rows="4" data-placeholder-attr="Description of the {{ name }}"></textarea>
```

Hope this helps someone else... IE - urgh.

Comment: You should post this answer to the above mentioned question that was asked before. Then people can accept it there, and you can remove your own question from SO.

Comment: Ok, I was hesitant to highlight my own answer as the solution. Zsong pointed out that this is a bug - his link above is the answer. My directive is a temporary measure. Thanks.

Comment: Simply use `ng-attr-placeholder` instead of `placeholder`. No need for a new directive.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using angular-translate library (https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate).

Specifically when trying to use the "directive way" to translate on a dynamic text containing an index. I replaced the directive by the "filter way" to translate and the problem was solved.

Before:

`<div translate>{{ scope.textInArray[someIndex] }}</div>`

After:

`<div>{{ scope.textInArray[someIndex] | translate }}</div>`

Note: Not even including the "{{ ... }}" as attribute value for translate or replacing that by a function call solved my issue.