# How to change placeholder for single textbox in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi Friends I have radiobuttons 
**"%"** and **"Count"**

If i click "%" then In the text box "%"  Should be placeholder

If i click "Count" Then "Count" Should be placeholder for same textbox

Here Fiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/qbauuzj2/

**Html**

```
       <div class="winner-par">
        <p>Winner Parameter</p>
        <div class="onoffswitch-green2">
          <input type="radio" id="radios5" name="radiosg5" class="SwitchOn" value="true" checked 
         ng-click="radioChecked()">
          <label for="radios5">%</label>
          <input type="radio" id="radios6" name="radiosg5" class="SwitchOff" value="false" ng-click="radiounChecked()">
          <label for="radios6">Count</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can dynamically update DOM-elements

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="Controller">
    ...
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
</div>
```

Your controller

```
function Controller($scope) {

    $scope.radioChecked = function ()
    {
        $scope.placeholder="%";
        $scope.apply();
    }

    $scope.radiounChecked = function ()
    {
        $scope.placeholder="Count";
        $scope.apply();
    }
}
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/z21qfwqz/14/

If you use >1.1.3 angular version - better way for this ng-attr-placeholder(thanks for **Teq1**)

```
<input type="text" ng-attr-placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
```

[Look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/z21qfwqz/18/)

Comment: TIP: It's better to use ng-attr-placeholder due to interpolation issues in IE => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647572/angularjs-v1-2-5-script-error-with-textarea-and-placeholder-attribute-using-ie11/24272011#24272011

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example:

[Change value of input placeholder via model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713137/change-value-of-input-placeholder-via-model)

Depending on which is selected, change the value of the "placeholder" variable in your scope, then bind that variable to the placeholder attribute on the element.