# AngularJS 1.1.5, Internet Explorer and ng-show with objects (Bug)

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs

Recently I had a bug in my app. A box was shown but it shouldn't. It was initialized this way:

```
<div ng-show="NewGroup">...</div>
```

and behind the scenes

```
$scope.NewGroup = null;
```

but Internet Explorer (both 9 and 10) were so stubborn and showed this box ALWAYS. The solution was to link the showing/hiding to the **$location** object.

Has anyone encountered this problem already? What is the best way to handle it? Is it an IE bug or an Angular bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been found. This constellation: IE 10+, AngularJS and textareas seems to be buggy.

```
<textarea ng-model="NewGroup.description" placeholder="Some placeholder"></textarea>
```

This evaluates to

```
$scope.NewGroup = { description: "" }
```

and causes the box to be shown. Closing the textarea node on itself solves the issue.

```
<textarea ng-model="NewGroup.description" placeholder="Some placeholder" />
```

Comment: This solution introduces new issues in AngularJS. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24289332/476786

Answer (score 1):

I always add the hide class to make sure the element is hidden when loading, also adding the css class as inline style for the page:

```
<style>
    .ng-hide { display: none!important; }
</style>
...
<div ng-show="NewGroup" class="ng-hide">...</div>
```

Comment: I think the more proper way to do this is **ng-cloak**, but I can be wrong.

Comment: For some reasons ng-cloak was not even hiding and adding class ng-hide just did a perferct job. thanks Kris