# Self-closing Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, angularjs, textarea

Related to this [AngularJS on IE10+ ,textarea with placeholder cause "Invalid argument."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224698/angularjs-on-ie10-textarea-with-placeholder-cause-invalid-argument) and this [AngularJS 1.1.5, Internet Explorer and ng-show with objects (Bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833668/angularjs-1-1-5-internet-explorer-and-ng-show-with-objects-bug) we have to use the **textarea** element as a self-closing tag to solve both issues in Internet Explorer.

But it is actually *wrong* to do so. Textarea is *not* a self-closing tag. In Chrome for example, using AngularJS, we get evil bugs and a broken document structure.

What solved my issue for now, was this:

```
<textarea ng-model="..." placeholder="..." /> <!--</textarea> -->
```

This makes it work properly in IE *and* Chrome. But it's very dirty and I don't like it all. Hopefully there is anyone here who has a better solution for this strange problem.

Cheers

Comment: Is this XHTML? It would be well-formed in XHTML. In normal HTML, it's physically impossible for a textarea to be self closing. This example would close it halfway the comment and then display `-->` on the screen after. So... do the Agularjs routines change the DOM differently for IE than for Chrome? What does the resulting outputted HTML actually look like?

Comment: I decided not to do any tricks. I will remove all dependencies in my application which rely on textarea-bound models and do a work-around. Dirty tricks must not be used in a quality project... Maybe this issue will be solved in newer Angular versions. Thank you for the time you spent reading this post. Cheers

Comment: Hope someone from the AngularJS team answers. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953#issuecomment-50456750

Comment: got an issue with self closed text area. in my case the text area was self closed and it didnt render anything below. after removing self closed tag it worked

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you simple use

```
<textarea  placeholder="..."> {{ngmodel}} </textarea>
```

instead of binding it to a ng-model